# C++ selecting a number of random items without repeating

Tags: c++

> Write a program that randomly selects from a bag of eight objects.
>   Each object can be red, blue, orange, or green, and it can be a ball or a cube.
>   Assume that the bag contains one object for each combination (one red ball, one
>   red cube, one orange ball, one orange cube, and so on). Write code similar to
>   Example 5.3, using two string arrays—one to identify colors and the other to
>   identify shapes.

I am trying to write a program to carry out the above exercise - the problem I am having is the same object can be selected more than once each time.

This is the code so far

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int rand_0toN1(int n);
void choose_object();

char *colour[4] =
    {"Red", "Blue", "Orange", "Green"};
char *object[2] =
    {"Ball", "Cube"};

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    srand(time(NULL)); // Set seed for randomizing.
    while (1) {
        cout << "Enter no. of objects to draw ";
        cout << "(0 to exit): ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n == 0)
            break;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            choose_object();
    }
    return 0;
}
void choose_object() {
    int c; // Random index (0 thru 4) into
    // colours array
    int o; // Random index (0 thru 2) into
    // object array
    c = rand_0toN1(4);
    o = rand_0toN1(2);
    cout << colour[c] << "," << object[o] << endl;
}

int rand_0toN1(int n) {
    return rand() % n;
}
```

Comment: The standard procedure is to generate a list of possibilities, shuffle them, then return those in the (shuffled) order.

Comment: @MooingDuck That isn't standard in anything of this sort I've seen. Imagine 10 criteria with 5 options each - you want to generate almost 10 million entries to find a handful? :-\

Comment: @glowcoder: Most shuffles rarely have more than a couple hundred, and I've never seen any other way.  Obviously it doesn't scale well, and for large numbers you'll need a nonstandard shuffling procedure.  What have you seen?

Comment: Thanks for quick responses - don't think i made my question very clear - I have only started trying to teach myself from a book over the last week so apologies if this doesn't make that much sense - the program asks to pick a number of objects out of the bag if I select 5 for example sometimes I will get the same combination more than one e.g red,ball red,ball - this is what I am trying to filter out

Comment: @Duck I have seen that implemented for some things (shuffling a deck of cards, for instance). There is no *standard procedure* for things like this. You'll note that in my answer I allude to that solution as my alternative option, while the primary option would be to store what you've picked as you go. This lends itself to the same scaling problem only it scales based on how much you pick as opposed to how big your problem-space is.

Comment: @glowcoder: I misunderstood your comment.  I listed the normal procedure for retrieving all objects in a random order.  For retrieving a small number of a large list, [CanSpice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8527909/845092)'s answer is far superior.

Comment: I have just read on in the book and it says Use an approach in which you generate one random number for each object picked and then use this number to generate a unique combination of two numbers—
one that selects the color and another that selects the shape. Does this tie in with the answer given as i'm struggling to understand this element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to give an exact answer, but describe what you could do:

1. Keep a list of objects you've already chosen.
2. After you choose an object, compare that object to the list of objects you've already chosen. If it's in the list, choose another object. If it's not in the list, add it to the list.
3. Make sure that you don't try to choose more than 8 objects, or else you'll end up in an infinite loop in part 2.

These would go in your `choose_object()` subroutine. You could do it in a `while()` loop, something like:

```
int seen_before = 0;
while(!seen_before) {
  pick your random numbers
  if(numbers not in list) {
    add to list
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't like this procedure.  While simple to comprehend, it gets quite slow.  The standard shuffle then iterate is much faster.

Comment: If you're only picking a small portion of the full set though, this is far faster than the shuffle I mentioned.

Comment: I prefer shuffling a list as Mooing Duck said, even if just to get rid of the feeling that this _might_ end up in an endless loop.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I've upvoted all of Mooing Duck's comments here.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to solve this by making a real world analogy:

Let's say you have a massive jar of marbles, of the colors listed above. It's so massive (infinite size!) that you always have the same chance to draw a marble of a given color, always 1/4 each time.

How would you do this in real life? Would you just keep picking randomly, chucking the marble away as you draw it? Or would you maybe keep a little list of things you've drawn already?

Or maybe you only have one of each in the jar... You wouldn't put it back in would you? Because that's kind of what you're doing here.

Each of these thought paths will lead you to a good solution. I don't want to provide a code or anything because this kind of assignment is one that teaches you how to think like a computer.